# how to deploy django app with python 3.8.1 to heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy django app to heroku. I am getting error when I install django-heroku. It's getting failed. The error is

> pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source

I tried to install psycopg2 too.It is also getting failed. I am using MacOS 10.15.4 and Python 3.8.1. How can I solve this error to deploy django app?

Comment: how do you deploy? Docker? CLI?

Answer (score 2):

Put

```
psycopg2-binary
```

in your requirements.txt

Comment: I did. but the error is now.  ` No module named 'genius.wsgi' `  and ` Reason: Worker failed to boot.`

Comment: i think genius.wsgi is refering to your app name and wsgi is a py file inside your project.
go to Procfile and copy here what have you typed there